# Selecting button with specific text only to activate on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row of buttons with the only difference between them their inner text:

```
<a href="#contact" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Text1</a>
<a href="#contact" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">text2</a>
<a href="#contact" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">text3</a>
```

I want to activate a script  only when the button with 'text3' is pushed . I tried the following but this works for all the buttons not just 'text3'.

```
$(function(){
$('a.btn[text()="text3"]').click(function(){

    console.log(id);
//        some action here

 });
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't you add a class to the link 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector so you only bind the event handler to a specific anchor that contains that text

```
$('a.btn:contains(text3)').click(function(){ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Jquery should be

```
    $("a.btn:contains('text3')").click(function(){
    alert("text3");
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/prTrv/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `.filter` and `.text` over `:contains`

```
$('a.btn').filter(function () {
   return $(this).text() == 'text3'
}).click(function () {
   alert('clicked');
});
```